# The difference between a YIELD statement and a GROUP combined YIELD clause in Nebula Graph

Tags: nebula-graph

```
FETCH PROP ON person "..." YIELD properties(person).name as name, properties(vertex).age as age
| GROUP BY $-.name YIELD $-.name, max($-.age) as max_age

FETCH PROP ON person "..." YIELD properties(person).name as name, properties(vertex).age as age
| YIELD $-.name, max($-.age) as max_age
```

As title, is there a difference between using the YIELD statement independently and the GROUP combination YIELD clause?

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent syntax. The yield clause of native ngql supports both implicit and explicit groupby, where implicit groupby behavior is consistent with cypher standards. For details，see [neo4j docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#:%7E:text=Grouping%20keys%20are%20non%2Daggregate%20expressions%2C%20that%20are%20used%20to%20group%20the%20values%20going%20into%20the%20aggregate%20functions.).